# reactjs app fetch() returning mobile html

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, fetch

the fetch function in my react app returns the html of the mobile version of the website. when i use `fetch()` with the URL in vanilla JavaScript, i get the original full desktop html.

- so far i have tried the following
- using header: {"User-Agent": 'Mozilla/5.0}
- using request library instead of the fetch library
- i have tired changing urls, but still i get the mobile version of the html

```
    import React, { Component } from 'react';
    import './App.css';
    import { FormGroup, FormControl, InputGroup, Form, } from 'react-bootstrap'


    class App extends Component {
      constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
          query: '',
          fimg: [],
        }
        this.OnSearch = this.OnSearch.bind(this);
      }

      OnSearch() {

        url = "https://www.zerochan.net/Re%3AZero+Kara+Hajimeru+Isekai+Seikatsu?s=fav"
        let headers = new Headers({
          "Accept": "application/json",
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
          "User-Agent": 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2272.101 Safari/537.36'
        });


        fetch(url, {
          header: headers,

        })
          .then(res => res.text())
          .then(body => {
            console.log(body)
              .catch(function (err) {
                console.log(err);

              });
          });
      }
      render() {
        return (
          <div className="App" >
            <div className="App-title"> Anime Images Galary</div>
            <Form>
              <FormGroup>
                <Form.Label>Enter the name of an Anime series below </Form.Label>
                <InputGroup className="formSize">
                  <FormControl
                    size="lg"
                    type="text"
                    placeholder="Search for an Artist"
                    value={this.state.query}
                    onChange={event => { this.setState({ query: event.target.value }) }}
                    onKeyPress={event => {
                      if (event.key === 'Enter') {
                        this.OnSearch()
                      }
                    }
                    }
                  />
                </InputGroup>
              </FormGroup>
              <button type="button" onClick={() => this.OnSearch()}>search</button>
            </Form>
            <div className="Profile">
            </div>
            <div>
              {images}
            </div>
          </div>
        )
      }

      export default App;
```

Comment: Why are you using application/json if you are fetching a html?

Comment: i have changed the header to "text/plain" and tired without the header agent, but it returns the same. it fetches the html as if i was using a mobile phone

Answer (score 1):

The fetch inside react does not set cookies by default and the website - when cookies are not detected - will redirect to the mobile version.

Please try to add:

```
  fetch(url, {
      credentials: "same-origin",
      header: headers,
    }).then(...).catch(...);
```